# How to automatically add target="_blank" to external links only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm building a custom, industry-specific cms (using django).  In the backend, webmasters can specify either an internal link, e.g. "/page1" or an external link to use for various navigation elements throughout the website (all use `<a>` when rendered) .  The problem is that I would like internal links to open in the current tab, but external links should use `target="_blank"` to open a new tab or window.

How can I process the html to accomplish this?

I'd prefer a server-side solution, but am not aware of any clean way to pre-process rendered templates in django. So, I assume the most straightforward way to do this is probably a javascript/jquery solution: a script that runs when each page loads, which adds the target="_blank" attribute to all external links but not internal links.  But I'm not sure how to do this, either.

Comment: I just edited it to make the formerly (and fairly obviously) implicit question explicit.

Comment: id do that on server side with a middleware which parses the response and replaces the code at the desired locations. You could use beautifulsoup for parsing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've been using the following for awhile. Can't remember where I found it originally:

```
$.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
    return !obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/)
           && (obj.hostname != location.hostname)
           && !obj.href.match(/^javascript\:/)
           && !obj.href.match(/^$/)
};
```

That adds an `:external` jQuery selector, so then you can just do:

```
$('a:external').attr('target', '_blank');
```

The nice part about using the custom selector, is that if you need to modify what contitutes an "external" link, you can change it in one place and not worry about the rest of your code. For instance in my organization, we have certain subdomains that aren't "external", but that we still want to open in new windows.

Comment: that is cool.  I've never extended jquery that way before, but i like simple usage, along with the advantages you mention.

Comment: This method of determining if the hostname is on- or off-site is very nice. Much more thorough than mine.

Comment: I've been using this without issue in production for years, and obviously at least 17 other people think it works. How did it not work for you? Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 8):

Try something like

```
for (var links = document.links, i = 0, a; a = links[i]; i++) {
        if (a.host !== location.host) {
                a.target = '_blank';
        }
}
```

Don't forget to run the script by the time all links exist in the document tree - in `window.onload` event.

Comment: I think using jQuery's .ready() would be more suitable instead of window.onload since .ready() fires as soon as the DOM is fully loaded while window.onload doesn't fire until all resources has been loaded (images etc.) which means there's a chance the user clicks before the target has been added.

Comment: @strille The question was not tagged jQuery so I didn't want to use it plus I didn't want OP to be confused with `DOMContentLoaded` + fallback solutions because it's not cross-browser. But you're right.

Comment: sorry about forgetting the initial jquery tag. Feel free to revise answer with jquery if you want.  Either way, I upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
$(document.body).on('mouseover', 'a[target!=_blank]:not(.local)', function (evt) {
    var a = $(this);
    var href = a.attr('href');
    var domain = href.match(/^https?:\/\/([^:\/]+)/);
    if (domain && domain[1] && domain[1] !== "yourdomain.com") {
        a.attr('target', '_blank');
    } else {
        a.addClass('local');
    }
});
```

This will process each link as you click it, and shouldn't process each link more than once. If it needs to be external, the `target` will be set to `_blank` and it should open in a new window. [Here's a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mU3Pm/11/).

**Update**: My method of determining if the link stays on-site or not is quite crude. The method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12042162/777929) is more thorough. I would probably replace my simple regex match with that test instead.

Comment: interesting real-time solution.

Comment: Not quite working yet. Have to help with an interview now, but will come back to edit in a bit.

Comment: I think i like Chris's answer better, but I already upvoted yours. So feel free to clean it up; just thought I'd give you the heads up I'm probably going a different direction, so no hurry.

Comment: His is a good answer. The single way I can think of where mine has an advantage is that you can add links dynamically with javascript, and they will automatically work without you having to run this code again. That's the beauty of the `.on` function :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you do that server side.
Modify the template of the page depending on the locality of the link.

Comment: While I can appreciate your sentiment, I think I'll wait and see if someone actually can suggest how that could be done server-side with django.

Answer (score 1):

Another JavaScript solution:

```
(() => {
  (document.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(link => {
    link.hostname !== location.hostname && link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  })
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

As the great accepted answer from @Chris Pratt does not work for e.g. tel: links and other special cases I just use the following variant in order to not touch special links:

```
(function($) {

    $.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
        return (obj.hostname != location.hostname) && obj.href.startsWith("http");
    };

    $('a:external').attr('target', '_blank');

}) (jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

`$("a[href^='http://']").attr("target","_blank");`

or

```
$('a').each(function() {
   var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
   if(!a.test(this.href)) {
       $(this).click(function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           event.stopPropagation();
           window.open(this.href, '_blank');
       });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight change in code, which doesn't give errors, additional = in !==

```
$.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
    return !obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/) && (obj.hostname !== location.hostname) && !obj.href.match(/^javascript\:/) && !obj.href.match(/^$/);
};
$('a:external').attr('target', '_blank');
```